# Alarm fires if the time is eariler than the current system time in android

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I am using alarm manager to assign the alarm at specific time. I encountered a problem which is if I set the time earlier than the current system time, then the alarm action will be fired  instantly. How to prevent this behavior ? Thanks

My code:

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,AlarmService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, serviceIntent, 0);

/*sample of setting eariler time
timeAlarm.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
timeAlarm.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
timeAlarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 13);
timeAlarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
timeAlarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
timeAlarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
*/
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeAlarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the android alarm manager is designed by this.
You can modify your time if the time earlier than the current system time by 1 day or more.
like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();        
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);

if (c.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()){
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Comment: This code has a problem when system time and calendar have the same time in hour and minute but different in seconds. It will add another day and that is wrong.